# Select group only if every element meets criteria

Tags: mysql, ms-access

I have simple database scheme like this: `Child one----many SchoolPreferences`

Children table consists of:

```
ChildId, Name, Surname, Age
```

SchoolPreferences consists of:

```
PreferenceId, ChildId, PreferenceNumber, SchoolName
```

This is for recrutation to school. Each kid can select max of 3 schools where they want to go to. If they get accepted in PreferenceNumber 1 then they go to 
that school, if they don't meet the conditions they get to PreferenceNumber 2 and if they fail there then their last chance is in third preference school.

I need to select schools that have only been chosen as PreferenceNumber 1. So if any child selected the school as PreferenceNumber 2 or 3 that school should NOT appear in the result at all.

So far I only know how to select individual rows, but what I need is to filter groups, so each school is a group and if any of preferences > 1 then this whole group should not appear in the result.

So far I have this, but as I said it only works for individual rows, not schools:

```
select SchoolPreferences.PreferenceId,
    Children.name,
    Children.Surname
from Children
inner join SchoolPreferences on Children.ChildId = SchoolPreferences.ChildId
group by SchoolPreferences.PreferenceId,
    Children.name,
    Children.Surname
having (((SchoolPreferences.PreferenceNumber) = 1));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An anti-join pattern would do the trick. The children table isn't needed. It looks like the only identifier we have for a school is `schoolname`.

If I'm understanding the specification, return the list of schools (`schoolname`) which appeared ONLY as preferencenumber 1, and did not appear as any other preferencenumber...

Something like this:

```
 SELECT p1.schoolname
   FROM SchoolPreferences p1
   LEFT
   JOIN SchoolPreferences pn
     ON pn.schoolname = p1.schoolname
    AND pn.preferencenumber <> 1
  WHERE pn.schoolname IS NULL
    AND p1.preferencenumber = 1
  GROUP
     BY p1.schoolname
```

---

There are other query patterns that return an equivalent result, e.g.

```
 SELECT p1.schoolname
   FROM SchoolPreferences p1
  WHERE p1.preferencenumber = 1
    AND NOT EXISTS 
        ( SELECT 1
            FROM SchoolPreferences pn
           WHERE pn.schoolname = p1.schoolname
             AND pn.preferencenumber <> 1
        )
  GROUP
     BY p1.schoolname
```

---

If we're looking to include the children that had the school as preferencenumber 1,  we remove the GROUP BY, and we can do a join to the `Children` table

```
 SELECT p1.schoolname

      , p1.preferenceid
      , p1.childid
      , ch.name
      , ch.surname

   FROM SchoolPreferences p1

   JOIN Children ch
     ON ch.childid = p1.childid

   LEFT
   JOIN SchoolPreferences pn
     ON pn.schoolname = p1.schoolname
    AND pn.preferencenumber <> 1
  WHERE pn.schoolname IS NULL
    AND p1.preferencenumber = 1

  ORDER
     BY p1.schoolname
      , p1.childid
```